# how to get the text from JSON response using simple java code

Tags: java, json

Hi all I am getting the below response when execute a REST request.

```
["A103388","R101858","R5575"]
```

but I need the values between the braces []. I tried using the `split()` and `replace()` but not able to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

No Need to **SPLIT** . If you playing with **JSONObject**

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response_message); //["A103388","R101858","R5575"]
for(int i = 0; i<object.length() ; i++)
{
    String getValue= object.get(i);
}
```

**Another Way**

```
 String getValue="your_respose";
 String [] getSplit=getValue.split(",");

        for(int i = 0; i < getSplit.length; i++)
        {

            System.out.println("Amiyo"+getSplit[i]);
        }
```

Comment: wouldn't this be a JSONArray ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the individual values, you can use the following code:

```
String input = "[\"A103388\",\"R101858\",\"R5575\"]"
String[] parsedInput = input.replaceAll("[\[\]]", "").split(",")
```

This code will replace all brackets with nothing, essentially removing it (`input.replaceAll("[\[\]]", "")`), after which it is split on the comma (`.split(",")`). This results in a String array, which has each of the requested elements as elements.

Comment: hi Max but my input does not contain the \ after the braces,

Comment: The backslashes are used to escape the brackets, which also have a meaning in [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). With these backslashes, the brackets after them are interpreted literally.